# PHP in IIS url rewrite with query string

Tags: php, iis, url-rewriting

In the browser I want this url:

http://my.website.com/Something/Action?param1=a&param2=b

This should call the page:

http://my.website.com/index.php?c=Something&a=Action&p1=a&p2=b

I've searched Google and Stackoverflow, but nothing works. Or IIS gives a 400 or de query string in the friendly url does not work.
This is driving me crazy!

This is what I have now:

```
<rule name="Clean extra question mark from query string" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.+)/(.+)$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php?controller={R:1}&amp;action={R:2}&amp;params={C:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

With the URL my.website.com/Page/Part?a=1 it works fine. But when I use this url:
my.website.com/Page/Part?a=1&b=2 I see a=1, but I don't see b=2... The number of params in the query string can be different.

Note the PHP is hosted in IIS 7.5 and I'm using the rewrite module of IIS.
Also note that the query string is not a fixed length. Somethimes it can have 2 items (param1 and param2) or more (or less).

Does someone has the anwser to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your question and post what you last tested?

Comment: See my original post: I've added it

Comment: What if you remove the conditions and the `&amp;params={C:1}` at the end of the rewrite? you already have `appendQueryString="true"` so it should do the job!

Comment: I was thinking in the wrong direction. I can figure out the page and the part. When I know those two I also know the params in the query string. With $_GET["a"] (and appendQueryString on true) it works. Stupid! Tomorrow starts my vacation, and by the looks of it, I really need it!